# How to paste all DriveApp activity into a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

```
function bothFilesAndFolders(){
 var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
 var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

 while(folders.hasNext() && files.hasNext()){
   var folder = folders.next();
   var file = files.next();
   var ff = ["folder Id ="+folder.getId(),"folder Name ="+folder.getName(),"folder date created="+folder.getDateCreated(),"file Id ="+file.getId(),"file Name ="+file.getName(),"file date created="+file.getDateCreated()];
   console.log(ff);
 }
}
```

So my above code logs all activities of all files and folders.
**GOAL:** I would like to know how do I push all this information into an active Spreadsheet.

Comment: I see you have another question about listing (logging) all files within a folder, so what is your real project and need: to search for files within a specific folder, or to search for all folders and files? In the last scenario if you have a basic Gmail account and have a lot of files, you might end up with a timeout (i.e. script fails to complete the task).

Comment: My goal in this current question is that whatever information that is being console logged by the above code, I would like to have the information to be instead printed out into an active spreadsheet. The previous question has nothing to do with this one.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I hope my question was correct.. 
The answer was a simple one line code.

```
function bothFilesAndFolders(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
 var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

 while(folders.hasNext() && files.hasNext()){
   var folder = folders.next();
   var file = files.next();
   var ff = ["folder Id ="+folder.getId(),"folder Name ="+folder.getName(),"folder date created="+folder.getDateCreated(),"file Id ="+file.getId(),"file Name ="+file.getName(),"file date created="+file.getDateCreated()];
   console.log(ff);

   sheet.appendRow(ff);
 }
}
```

I kept trying to use push but it was not showing up on the spreadsheet, turns out I had to use appendRow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the info for each `ff` in a different cell of a Spreadsheet, you simply need to access a cell of the sheet at each different iteration and set its value to the stringified array (so that we set all the elements of that array in that cell). This is the implementation for what you are aiming for (with self explanatory comments):

```js
function myfunction(){
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  // get the spreadsheet and sheet we will be working on. Also initialise the variable
  // we will be using to keep track of the iteration number (and therefore write in a 
  // different cell
  var url = 'SPREADSHEETURL';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  var i = 1;
  
 while(folders.hasNext() && files.hasNext()){
   var folder = folders.next();
   var file = files.next();
   var ff = ["folder Id ="+folder.getId(),"folder Name ="+folder.getName(),"folder date created="+folder.getDateCreated(),"file Id ="+file.getId(),"file Name ="+file.getName(),"file date created="+file.getDateCreated()];
   
   // in this case I am setting the ff info to the first column of the sheet. i here is the 
   // row number which means that over each iteration we will be setting the next row to the
   // right value. That is why we also need to increment i by one on each iteration. 
   sheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue(ff.toString());
   i++;
 }
}
```